# Odd Sed Error Message

Tags: sed

```
bash-3.2$ sed -i.bakkk -e "s#/sa/#/he/#g" .*
sed: .: in-place editing only works for regular files
```

I try to replace every /sa/ with /he/ in every dot-file in a folder. How can I get it working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `find -type f` to find only *files* matching the name `.*` and exclude the directories `.` and `..`. `-maxdepth 1` prevents `find` from recursing into subdirectories. You can then use `-exec` to execute the `sed` command, using a `{}` placeholder to tell `find` where the file names should go.

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -exec sed -i.bakkk -e "s#/sa/#/he/#g" {} +
```

Using `-exec` is preferable over using backticks or `xargs` as it'll work even on weird file names containing spaces or even newlines—yes, `"foo bar\nfile"` is a valid file name. An honorable mention goes to `find -print0 | xargs -0`

```
find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bakkk -e "s#/sa/#/he/#g"
```

which is equally safe. It's a little more verbose, though, and less flexible since it only works for commands where the file names go at the end (which is, admittedly, 99% of them).

Comment: + at the end?  is it the same as ";" ?

Comment: ";" will run the command once per file, so 10 seds for 10 files. "+" will run it once passing *all* of the files, to 1 sed for 10 files.

Comment: You mean commands such as "rm .*" are unsafe to remove dotfiles? Should you prefer:    find . -name ".*" -exec rm '{}' \;     ?

Comment: If I understood right, ";" is inefficient, so + is preferred with a big number of files.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
sed -i.bakkk -e "s#/sa/#/he/#g"  `find .* -type f -maxdepth 0 -print`
```

This should ignore all directories (e.g., .elm, .pine, .mozilla) and not just . and .. which I think the other solutions don't catch.

Answer (score 2):

The glob pattern `.*` includes the special directories `.` and `..`, which you probably didn't mean to include in your pattern.  I can't think of an elegant way to exclude them, so here's an inelegant way:

```
sed -i.bakkk -e "s$/sa/#/he/#g" $(ls -d .* | grep -v '^\.\|\.\.$')
```

Comment: +1.  Recommend find/xargs:  find . -type f -maxdepth 1 -name '.*' | xargs sed ...